# How to combine multiple MySQL databases using D2RQ?

Tags: mysql, semantic-web, linked-data, d2rq

I have four different MySQL databases that I need to convert into Linked Data and then run queries on the aggregated data. I have generated the D2RQ maps separately and then manually copied them together into a single file. I have read up some material on customizing the maps but am finding it hard to do so in my case because:

1. The ontology classes do not correspond to table names. In fact, most classes are column headers.
2. When I open the combined mapping in Protege, it generates only 3 classes (ClassMap, Database, and PropertyBridge) and lists all the column headers as instances of these.
3. If I import this file into my ontology, everything becomes annotation.

Please suggest an efficient way to generate a single graph that is formed by mapping these databases to my ontology.

Here is an example. I am using the EEM ontology to refine the mapping file generated by D2RQ. This is a section from the mapping file:

```
map:scan_event_scanDate a d2rq:PropertyBridge;
    d2rq:belongsToClassMap map:scan_event;
    d2rq:property vocab:scan_event_scanDate;
    d2rq:propertyDefinitionLabel "scan_event scanDate";
    d2rq:column "scan_event.scanDate";
    # Manually added
    d2rq:datatype xsd:int;
    .
map:scan_event_scanTime a d2rq:PropertyBridge;
    d2rq:belongsToClassMap map:scan_event;
    d2rq:property vocab:scan_event_scanTime;
    d2rq:propertyDefinitionLabel "scan_event scanTime";
    d2rq:column "scan_event.scanTime";
    # Manually added
    d2rq:datatype xsd:time;
```

The ontology I am interested in has the following:

```
Data property: eventOccurredAt
Domain: EPCISevent
Range: datetime
```

Now, how should I modify the mapping file so that the date and time are two different relationships?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to generate a single graph of your 4 databases is to convert them one by one to a [Jena](https://jena.apache.org/) Model using D2RQ, and then use the [Union](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/rdf/model/Model.html#union%28com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Model%29) method to create a global model.
For your D2RQ mapping file, you should read carefully [The mapping language](http://d2rq.org/d2rq-language), it's not normal to have classes corresponding to columns.
If you give an example of your table structure, I can give you an illustration of a mapping file.
Good luck

Comment: Thank you for the response, Hatim. I set up the Sesame triplestore a while back. Is Sesame as efficient as Jena for this application? Right now, I am working on manually enriching the mapping files. Is it a good idea to combine them into a single file or should I let them be separate?